# Creating an anonymous link

Tags: html, header, referrer

I was wondering how I would be able to create an anonymous link (blanking the referrer) for redirection (so they are not 100% aware of where the client came from).

So for example, user visits `mydomain.com/product/2/` and wants to be redirected to the cheapest offer out there `othersite.com/product/aiwdkaDOW` important here is that the 'othersite' has to see this request as an manual input (so it looks like that the client wrote the url down in the URL bar).

Actually I just like to create the same effect [Linkonym](http://www.linkonym.com/) has

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymizing a link seems a little more complex to me (due to the fact that you don't want the target link to know that the traffic came from you) but as I expected, there are APIs and even [This GitHub project](https://github.com/katzwebservices/YOURLS-Link-Anonymizer/blob/master/plugin.php) that might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I red the code you sent me, but is pretty hard for me to understand. Trying to figure out the structure needed in order to write this 'function'. So basically, i'll be redirecting the client first to another PHP file, and from that file i'll be resetting the referrer and redirect him further to his destination?